# Proving the inverse relationship between exponential function and natural logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am working to prove that $E(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ and $L(x) = \displaystyle\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt $ are inverse functions to one another.

I have already found that $(L \circ E)(x) = x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, however I am struggling to prove that $(E \circ L)(x)=x$ for all $x > 0$.

My work for $L \circ E$ involved finding $(L \circ E)'(x) = 1$ to imply my result.

Any tips how to proceed for this $(E \circ L)$ result?

Thanks!

Comment: $L : (0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$ is bijective i.e. it has some inverse $L^{-1} : \Bbb R \to (0, \infty)$. Hence for all $x \in \Bbb R$, you can apply $L^{-1}$ on both sides of $(L \circ E)(x) = x$ to get $E(x) = L^{-1}(x)$ directly. You don't need $(E \circ L)(x) = x$.

Comment: @0XLR I understand how to show $L$ is injective based on $L$ being strictly monotonically increasing on $(0, \infty)$, but struggling a bit more showing surjectivity.

I know that $L$ is continuous on $(0, \infty)$, but not sure how to show surjectivity over $\mathbb{R}$ from this. I thought use the IVT but not sure how to rigorously use this.. Any further tips?

Comment: $L(x)$ is unbounded above: the lower Riemann sums of $\int_1^x 1/t\ dt$, evaluated at +ve integers below $x$, are just partial sums of the harmonic series; hence $L(x)$ can grow arbitrarily large and +ve. So, using $L(1) = 0$, you can use IVT to establish surjectivity for any $y > 0$.

Comment: For $0 < x < 1$, just rewrite $\int_1^x 1/t\ dt$ as $-\int_x^1 1/t\ dt$. Now look at the lower Riemann sums of $\int_x^1 1/t\ dt$, evaluated at the numbers $\{1/n\}_{n \in \Bbb Z_+}$ that fall between $x$ and $1$. These are just sums of consecutive integers. Hence $\int_x^1 1/t\ dt$ can grow arbitrarily large and +ve i.e. $L(x) = -\int_x^1 1/t\ dt$ can grow arbitrarily large and -ve. So $L$ is also unbounded below. So using $L(1) = 0$, you can use IVT to establish surjectivity for any $y < 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very thorough and has greatly helped my understanding. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $$\left(\frac{(E\circ L)(x)}{x}\right)'=\frac{x\,(E\circ L)'(x)-(E\circ L)(x)}{x^2}\\=\frac{x\,(E'\circ L)(x)L'(x)-(E\circ L)(x)}{x^2} = \frac{(E\circ L)(x)-(E\circ L)(x)}{x^2} = 0$$

Then $(E\circ L)(x) = cx$. Evaluate at $x=1$.

Comment: That's very much aligned with my technique for the first result. Adding the $x^2$ denominator makes this very easy indeed. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution in the same vein as your other direction. Let $$y(x)=(E\circ L)(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\left(\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt\right)^n\ .$$

Then we have

$$y(1) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\left(\int_1^1\frac{1}{t}dt\right)^n= 1\ ,$$

as each integral is $0$ for $n\geq 1$. Then you can differentiate $y$ to see

$$\begin{align}y'&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n!}\left(\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt\right)^{n-1}\frac{1}{x}\\
&=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\left(\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt\right)^{n-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{x}y\ . \end{align}$$

Then we have the initial value problem

$$\begin{align}y'=\frac{1}{x}y\\ y(1)=1\ , \end{align}$$

which has the unique solution $$(E\circ L)(x)=y(x)=x\ .$$

You may want to justify 1) the term by term differentiation and 2) the solution to the ODE.